# How can I not disable background interaction when alertdialog is shown in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

How can I not disable background interaction when the alertdialog is showing? While keeping the alertdialog on the screen 
Note that I use activity to display it like an alertdialog.

**Summary**

I wanna make the screen touchable when the alertdialog is showing.
And is there a way to do this from the manifest.xml folder?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: But the interaction with background will still disable

Comment: And i wanna way to do that from manifest XML. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Im not sure if this is possible with dialogs. Maybe you could try https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom#standard-bottom-sheet or just add "dialog content" to your activity XML and show/hide it when needed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with alert dialog. In one of my recent project I needed the same feature (A pop up where the outside element can be clicked even when pop up is shown).

The workaround was that I created a Relative Layout (Holding Views of my alert dialog) and put it inside root layout which was also a relative layout.

Initially visibility of inside relative layout was set to `Gone`. And I was just controlling the visibility of inside relative layout on button click. And When the pop up was being displayed, I was still able to click the element outside of inside relative layout.

One important thing, You need to set `android:elevation="20dp"` to your inside relative layout in order to overlap  and get the pop-up.

Comment: Thanks bro for this idea, can you give me this code please ?! You will help me a lot

Comment: https://github.com/buuzuu/DPS/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml
Link to my xml code.You just need to hide/unhide the visibility of relative layout who's ID is android:id="@+id/chart_layout"